# Regex for exclusion and inclusion criteria

Tags: python, regex

I need to write a Regex that can exclude a text if it includes a string but keeps the text if that string does not exist and the text includes a specific string. For the following text

```
text1 = "unable to reach and confirm the first choice of attempts made, vm last night left with call back number re soc poc."
```

I want to exclude the text if it includes "unable to reach", but keep the text if the "unable to reach" does not exist and the text includes "vm left".

This is my code:

```
(\b^(?!(unable to reach))(?:(note|vm)(?:\W+\w+){0,3}?\W+(left|leave))\b, text1)
```

It includes text1, but for text 2 cannot recognize "vm left" while the "unable to reach" does not exist.

```
text2 = " confirm the first choice of attempts made, vm last night left with call back number re soc poc."
```

Please help.

Comment: why you give it a negative vote? what is the problem with it?

Comment: When you omit the anchor `\b(?!unable to reach)(note|vm)(?:\W+\w+){0,3}?\W+(left|leave)\b` https://regex101.com/r/qbp0eF/1

Comment: What do you mean by, "exclude the text" and "include the text"? Do you mean you wish to determine whether the string contains `"vm"` and `"left"` and does not contain `"unable to reach"`? You said it must contain the string `"vm left"`, which is not the same as `"vm"` and `"left"`. And where did `"note"` and `"leave"` come from? You need to edit your question to clarify these points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code:

```
^(?=.*(?:(note|vm)(?:\W+\w+){0,3}?\W+(left|leave)))(?!.*(?:unable to reach))
```

You can check it in the https://regex101.com

Comment: Can you explain how the regexp solves the problem? Code-only answers are not as useful for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

```
pattern = re.compile('^(?!unable to reach).*(?:vm|note).*(?:left|leave).*', flags=re.IGNORECASE) 
re.findall(pattern, text1)
```